# How do i get property of an object instead of whole object on v-model in vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I had created an input form using html and given `v-model="upCountryName"`, which is an empty array by default but if once name value clicked I had written function to fetch the data from django db using djangorestframework and I had got the data also but in input from `v-model="upCountryName"` I am getting data as [object Object].

So I written `v-model="upCountryName.country"` which actually I want to update but input form showing empty, how can I get country name instead of whole object.

```
----------
HTML --

<td v-on:click="up_country_form(c.id)">
  <!--c.id is country.id i am getting from django db and passing it to the method up_country_form(id) in script-->
  <center>
    <p class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></p> 
    </center>
</td>
<input type="text" v-model='upCountryName.country' class="form-control">

----------
Vue.js

<script>
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        upCountryName: []
      };
    },
    methods: {
      up_country_form (id) {
        this.up_country_box = true;
        this.$http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/getCountry/'+id)
          .then((response) => {
            this.upCountryName = response.data;
            this.loading = false;
          });
        console.log(id);
        this.add_country_box = false;
      }
    }
  };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make sure `response.data` is in form like `{ country: "Some Country Name" }` then everything should work fine.

You can see the demo [here](http://jsbin.com/pobolobino/1/edit?html,js,output).

Note: if you use `upCountryName.country`, the type of `upCountryName` should be Object not Array.

```
data () {
  return {
    upCountryName: {}
  }
}
```

Comment: Still not working because the response data i ma getting from django rest api , even after your suggestions it's not working it showing the same object Object

Comment: What's the response data? Could you share some example of it?

Comment: [ { "country": "India" }] this is the response data bro

Comment: It's should be Object not Array. If you have some reasons to use Array you can use `this.upCountryName = response.data[index]` or in template use `v-model='upCountryName[index].country'`

Comment: Dear User28 it worked thank you but hwat i am getting doubt is i had fetched that data like same the way before i mentioned to evry where in page it worked well, but not in case of input form, is there any special case with binding json data with input forms....?

Comment: I believe there is no difference. You might have missed in something else.